# How to do this in SQL? (run a query over a window instead of just a single aggregate)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have some data with timestamps yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss and some error stages (1 meaning an error has occurred). I have the data loaded in a dataframe I call df and want to compute Time_To_Next_Error (measured in seconds) a new column  Time_To_Error based on the timestamp and Error_State.

```
Timestamp            Error_State  Time_To_Next_Error   
2017-05-10 00:10:50      0                10
2017-05-10 00:10:55      0                5 
2017-05-10 00:11:05      1                0
2017-05-10 00:11:10      0                5 
2017-05-10 00:11:15      1                0
2017-05-10 00:11:20      0                15
2017-05-10 00:11:25      0                10
2017-05-10 00:11:30      0                5
2017-05-10 00:11:20      1                0
2017-05-10 00:11:20      0                0
```

For example, the first observation, there's 15 seconds before the first error occurs at 11:05 after which the count starts over from 0 seconds then the next "window" starts.

Is there a way to define a "window" spanning the next say 5 rows so I can 'look ahead' and check if any of those 5 rows satisfy some condition (like say one of the values is a 1 meaning an Error_Stage = 1 will happen soon)

Comment: what is the version of SQL Server that you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you're saying -- a window function!

Here's some code, SQL Server style:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
ts datetime,
Error_st int
);

INSERT INTO @tbl 
VALUES 
('2017-05-10 00:10:50',      0),
('2017-05-10 00:10:55',      0),
('2017-05-10 00:11:05',      1),
('2017-05-10 00:11:10',      0),
('2017-05-10 00:11:15',      1),
('2017-05-10 00:11:20',      0),
('2017-05-10 00:11:25',      0),
('2017-05-10 00:11:30',      0),
('2017-05-10 00:11:35',      1),
('2017-05-10 00:11:40',      0)

select *, DATEDIFF(second, ts, 
                    min(CASE WHEN error_st=1 then ts else NULL END) 
                    over (order by ts desc)) as time_to_Next_Err
--  , min(CASE WHEN error_st=1 then ts else NULL END) 
--    over (order by ts desc) as NextErrorTS
from @tbl
order by ts
```

Here we rely on default behaviour of the SQL Server window-version of `MIN()`:
the window is defined as "all previous rows and current" (ordering by descending timestamp). You can control the window and limit it to the "5 previous", if you only want to show "close-to-error" situations.

More details here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  DATEDIFF(second,
    timestamp,
    MIN(CASE WHEN error > 0 THEN timestamp END) OVER(ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 5 FOLLOWING
  ) as ttne 
FROM yourtable
```

This will get the lowest(soonest) time stamp in the following 5 rows where the  error code that occurs is greatest than 0, and datediff it with the timestamp of the current row

You could adjust the case when to do different logic

```
--time to next error code 1
MIN(CASE WHEN error = 1 THEN ...
```

If there is no error code 1 in the next 5 rows this should result in a null and datediff should also then output a null